# How to handle no matches case in List.First in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In [IEnumerable.First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) function, how do I handle the case if there are no matches? Currently it just crashes...

```
MySPListItem firstItem = itemCollection.First(item => !item.isFolder);
if (firstItem != null)
{
    TreeNode firstNode = GetNodeByListItem(my_treeview.Nodes, firstItem, ReportObject);
    if (firstNode != null)
    {
        ReportObject.log("Selecting the first PDF");
        selectPDF(my_treeview, firstNode, queryStr_param);
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> Sequence contains no matching element
>   Stacktrace:    at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
>   predicate)

Comment: If there is no match it will return the default value for that type.. (`null` for a class, the default for a struct). Put your code and we'll be able to tell you where the error is happening.

Comment: I do a null check, but it crashes on the line where I use Find...

Comment: As an alternative, why not use LINQ's FirstOrDefault(item => item.item.ID == PDFID)

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: I added the exception message. Also I changed it to .First, although I also use .Find, and want to know the right way to fix this.

Comment: The behaviour of First and Find is different. First will throw an exception if there is no match. See @Dann comment.

Comment: it just crashes? You mean, it throws an exception befause there is no first.

Comment: whats the point of throwing an exception, isn't returning a null just easier to deal with?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok, If it is **exceptional** for there to be no first,

```
try
{
    var first = enumerable.First();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    // Oops, that was exceptional.
}
```

If you anticipate that there may be no first in some valid situations,

```
var first = enumerable.FirstOrDefault();
if (first == default(someType)) // null for reference types.
{
    // Ok, I need to deal with that.
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one. Concise, and considers *why* the exception is thrown.

Comment: Whats the difference between `default(someType)` and `null`?

Comment: @omega `default(T)` returns the default value of a type. For a reference type this is always `null` so, in your case they are interchangeable. If you want the code to work with value types (structs and primitives) then `default(T)` provides a generic solution. Of course, if you know the type, you could just use a literal equal to the default value, its what the compiler does for you anyway.

Answer (score 7):

While you do a `null` check on the find, you don't in your predicate. The line

```
    foundItem = itemCollection.Find(item => item.item.ID == PDFID);
```

Might throw an exception it `item` is `null` (have you inserted an `null` item in the collection?) or `item.item` is `null` (are you sure it's always there?).

You could do:

```
foundItem = itemCollection.Find(item => item != null &&
                                        item.item != null && 
                                        item.item.ID == PDFID);
```

More chatty, but you won't get a `NullReferenceException`.

**Edit** Well you changed your question. Now you do `First`.  The `First` method **will** throw an exception if nothing is found. Use `FirstOrDefault` instead which will return `null` for a class or the default value for a `struct`.

```
    foundItem = itemCollection.FirstOrDefault(item => item != null &&
                                              item.item != null && 
                                              item.item.ID == PDFID);
```

Comment: I added the exception message. I don't think it is because the item is null.

Comment: See my update. You changed the method (it was `Find` but it's `First` now)

Answer (score 3):

Replace First by [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) :

```
MySPListItem firstItem = itemCollection.FirstOrDefault(item => !item.isFolder);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from the [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) you linked to:

> The first element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type T.

This describes the return value. Hence, when no match is found, the `default` value for type `T` is returned, which means `null` for reference types, and things such as `0`, `false` & co. for value types.

So in your calling code, simply check for this default value, and you're fine :-). What you can not do is just use the value that is being returned, as this e.g. might result in a `NullReferenceException`, if you are using a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the result is `null`:

```
   if (result == null)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Not found");
   }
```

There is a clear example demonstrating what to do if the item is found/not found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't throw an exception, you need to handle the case where it returns default(T). You might be getting a NullReferenceException because you're not handling the case where it returns null. For example:

```
IEnumerable<Cars> cars = GetCars();
Car car = cars.Find(c => c.Model == "Astra");
if(car != null) 
{
   // You found a car!
}
```

If you were doing the same for a struct, you'd check for it's default instead. Ints for example would be a 0:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 4, 7 };
int myInt = ints.Find(i => i > 5);
if(myInt != 0) // 0 is default(int)
{
   // You found a number
}
```